# More modern version of jQuery UI Draggable component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a .NET Razor Pages application and need draggable/sortable functionality.

I found the [jQuery UI Draggable/Sortable component](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable). I actually used this many years ago and it worked fine.

But the download page says it's stable for jQuery 1.8+ and I'm using jQuery 3.5.1.

Are there any newer versions of a draggable/sortable component?

*If it makes any difference, I'm using Bootstrap 5. And my objects to be dragged are `class="col-lg-6"` `<div>`s within a `class="row"` `<div>`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 3.5.1 is (much) newer than jQuery 1.8, so you are fine.
As for the draggable/sortable widgets, they are part of jQuery-UI and 1.13.2 is the newest version.